# SSIS + ADO.NET + oracle source + sql server destination + intermittent missing data

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, ado.net, dataflowtask

I've been reading data from oracle to sql server using Data Flow Tasks, its been working but there are times that no data would be returned. However when I run the query in oracle plsql developer, I can see data or preview the results in source component data would show.

The queries are form of expressions as I pass parameters.

Is there anything else I can check?

Thanks

Comment: My first thought is that the expression is not being built properly.  Have you validated that the expression is correct prior to the source connection to Oracle being fired?

Comment: I woud check variables. Maybe some of them are used in expresions but can be evaluates in other steps